# Does output current track input current, in a bridge rectifier?

Tags: rectifier, bridge

In a bridge rectifier, will output current vary in proportion to input current?

Or only voltage to voltage?

[image]

Comment: Um why wouldn't it.. where do you expect it to go/come from otherwise?

Comment: What Trevor writes: where would any current difference go? Nowhere so there is no difference. But be aware of different **definitions** of currents and voltages. AC can be peak, peak-peak or RMS while for DC there is no such thing (they're all the same). Note also that without a smoothing capacitor, the DC side is not really DC.

Comment: @Trevor obviously, if I knew the answer, I wouldn't be asking. Your snyde attitude is inappropriate. Feel better about making yourself feel superior by treating someone else like they're stupid?

Comment: it is not snyde it is a simple question intended to make you think?

Answer (score 7):

Ignoring the tiny leakage currents through reverse-biased diodes, the output current is not merely proportional to the input.  It must be the same.

Comment: Even *not* ignoring these currents it will be the same...

Comment: @Eug: No, leakage currents, could, for example, cause input current even when the output current is 0.  You *do* have to ignore these currents for this answer to be correct.  +1 to the answer, and shame on those upvoting your comment.

Comment: @OlinLathrop what would cause 0 output current? No load?

Comment: @johny: Leaving the output open guarantees 0 output current.

Comment: @OlinLathrop as true as that is... for any bridge rectifier current in must = current out... Now if the question was does the current on the right side of the indicated circuit change in proportion to the current on the left, then you would have to factor in leakage current. Whether that means it is no longer proportional, or is proportional using a formula that includes a constant, is a matter of debate.

Comment: @Trevor: It seems we have a different definition of what the output current is.  I take that to mean just the current that is delivered to the load.  Diode leakage is a third current that stays internal to the bridge.  Input = output + leakage.

Comment: @OlinLathrop ya that's my point. If you call a bridge-rectifier that funny four pin-part the question means something else. ;)

Comment: @Trevor: I'm not getting whatever point you are trying to make.

Comment: @OlinLathrop never mind.. I was just being pedantic.